# Different kind of Angular Directives patterns

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.directive('ppd:reset', function(e1,e2) {
    return function(linkElement) {      
        linkElement.wrap()....
        });
    };
});
```

And

```
angular.directive('ppd:reset', [function() {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {   } 

}]);
```

What is the difference between these two directives pattern ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you declare your factories with the bracket notation, you can avoid problems when minifying your code:

```
angular.directive('ppd:reset', ["$compile", function(compile) {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {   } 

}]);
```

The injector looks at your function parameter names in order to know what to inject. If a minification process renames those, The injector doesn't know what to do anymore. Minification will of course not touch string values which is why the array notation works fine.

Comment: You can find it in the DI documentation at the title "Inline Annotation" http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inlineannotation

Comment: Well, you can also use the less verbose syntax and parse source with ngMin :) https://github.com/btford/ngmin

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that version #1 is a simple way that angular does support for writing directives that don't require any injectable modules. The version #2 is for having injectables. So, let's say your directive relied on the $timeout service, then you would have a definition like below. For me, its easier to not think and just use the array syntax even if there are no injectables.

```
angular.directive('ppd:reset', ['$timeout', function($timeout) { 
       return function(scope, elm, attrs) {   } 
}]);
```

Comment: Angular still does dependency injection in both forms. The difference is in handling minification as the other answer implies.

Comment: I agree with the minification comment, however, the original post was (as I read it) was in regards to having an array versus not having an array. I hadn't thought about mentioning the minification bit. I don't see how my answer is wrong.

Comment: Your answer flat out says that the first syntax is for writing directives that don't require injection.. but that's not true. Angular will attempt to inject dependencies for both.

Comment: As I look at my answer I can see your point. Also, looking at the provided example it's actually a bit unclear as to what exactly is being asked for (at least to me) and I should've probably asked for clarification. But your points are taken. I'll revisit my solution and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that the `[]` bracket notation is minifier-safe as minifiers don't minify strings. For instance, if you try to minify javascript without it, it will turn:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
});
```

into

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("MainController",function(e){})
```

The issue in this case is that Angular doesn't know a thing about `e` as opposed to `$scope`, which it does know about. Using the `[]` bracket notation, we can tell the `$injector` in advance what we want the controller to get access. Since minifiers don't (and can't) minify strings, it's a safe way to use the **dependency injection** feature of Angular with or without minifiers.

For a deeper understanding of the differences of syntax, you can check out ng-book (https://www.ng-book.com/). Disclaimer, I am the author of the book and of http://www.ng-newsletter.com/.