# Angularjs minification being forced to add strings for services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, uglifyjs

As is documented in numerous places in angular you must put service names in an array in order to survive minification.

example:
[Different kind of Angular Directives patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711285/different-kind-of-angular-directives-patterns)

The problem I have with this is that it's really really ugly and you have to essentially put the service names twice. I also don't want to turn off mangling in uglifyjs.

Is there a way to automatically create the brackets in the build process or use some other method to take care of this problem automatically?

Comment: you should be doing it manually

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal what about ngmin as per Vitaliy's answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try ngmin - https://github.com/btford/ngmin.

But I prefer to add these annotations manually by myself.

Comment: @Harry if you follow the convention all should work fine.
But if you annotate dependencies manually your code 100% will work after minification.